# Error : Laravel Vendor Folder Upload Error - Shared Hosting

Tags: php, laravel-5

I've just finished a simple work done in Laravel 5.2 and I'm ready to Deploy on my server.

I found that the vendor folder has number of folders and I wonder if it is necessary to upload all its subfolders. I suppose that I don't use the most of those libraries, is there a good practise to follow to deploy a Laravel project?

*I get an error while uploading folder to server.*

**Laravel Vendor Folder Structure**
[image: Laravel Folder]

**Error While Uploading Vendor Folder**

[image: Error]

---

> P.S :: I have read somewhere that **You should not upload the vendor folder, insted you should run composer install/update on your server where you deploy. You should only deploy your application files.**

**Few points to be noted**

1. I haven't an ssh access on this server. I have only an FTP access.
2. And if it's a shared host (like many people have) without SSH, then how can i run **Composer**?